# how do I delete weblogic portal domain directory

Tags: server, weblogic

I am working on setup scripts for a weblogic portal domain. This requires me to create the domain / delete / try again many times. However I have found that when I start the server and kill it I can not delete the folder where the domain is saved (C:\portal-10.3.7\user_projects\domains\myDomain). There are some .DAT files which are used as part of some persistent file store and they keep getting created even when I kill the servers (C:\portal-10.3.7\user_projects\domains\myDomain\servers\AdminServer\data\store). Only way I can delete them is if I restart my computer. Ive tried killing processes from task manager and shutting down services but I cant seem to figure out what keeps generating these files. Other developers using the domain setup scripts have the same complaint.

Edit:
I found using a tool called "Process Explorer" that there is a process that is holding the file.
Process explorer mentions that PID #4 is using the file
When I run tasklist I can see that PID #4 has:

- Image Name=System
- Session=Services

I looked around and found this PID #4 is 'NT Kernel & system' so I cant kill it or the whole system will go down. Not sure if there is a specific dll I can kill or find which dll holds the file and just shut that down

I went so far as to download systinternals handle tool (microsofts own tool). Able to find the handle identifier but microsofts own tool is not able to release the handle. Infuriating how much time I have wasted.

edit ...
Last thing to mention and I officially give up. When I start the server I can see the servers java process owns the handle. When I shut down the server (using either the shutdown script or by killing the java process) I can see the system processes with PID 4 takes over the handle to the file.

Comment: No need to "kill" the server, just stop it with the admin console or with a wlst script or with the stop...sh script Stop also the node manager. After all, remove the domain directory. That's all. If you are running derby DB check also that the derby server is stopped before removing the directory

Comment: I kill the derby server and the weblogic server and I can not delete the directory. Both run as java processes and I have killed all java processes in task manager. Im able to delete the entire domain directory except for the data/store directory

Comment: By killing your server do you mean using the task manager to kill the java process ? You should use stop scripts instead.

Comment: hi either way the server stops whether you kill the java process or use the script. I also tried using stop server script and I can not delete the domain directory afterwards. This does not help me figure out what is keeping a hold of these files

Comment: It seems like there is some process or service keeping the file open. its a little difficult to figure it out since I have to use something called appSense to get any admin priviledges and it is flakey (developers at my company cant have direct admin access on our own machines). What I did find using a tool called "Process Explorer" is that there is a process that is holding the file. I find that PID #4 is locking the file. When I run tasklist I can see that PID #4 has Image Name=System and session=Services